# How are RxJS observables cancelling promises?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

- As far as I know right now we can't cancel promises

But when promises wrapped with RxJS Observables. I am able to unsubscribe to the stream even when stream is active. How are observables able to do it?

Comment: Can you give an example of Promise wrapped in Observable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The promise isn't actually canceled, rxjs just takes care of ignoring its result. You can try it out pretty easily:

```js
const promise = new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Resolving");
    resolve(42);
  }, 2000);
});

const obs$ = Rx.Observable.fromPromise(promise);
const sub = obs$.subscribe(console.log);
setTimeout(() => sub.unsubscribe(), 1000);
```

You'll see `Resolving` printed in the console, but no value from the observable.